# Replace in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, hotfix

I am trying to print out Microsoft update hot fix URLs and change them

```
    $link=Get-MSHotfix|Where-Object {$_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-20000))}|Select-Object -Property KBArticle 


foreach($line in $link){

        [String]$line = $line -replace 'http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=','https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/'


    [String]$line
}
```

I have problem because it prints it out like this  and it is not replacing:

```
@{KBArticle=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3045992}
@{KBArticle=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3045999}
@{KBArticle=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3046017}
@{KBArticle=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3046359}
@{KBArticle=http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3046737}
```

If I just print it without -replace it looks ok.

I am trying to get full URL of KB Article

I am trying to create a script with will print out all hot fixes with links and names from title if possible

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `-replace` argument is a Regular Expression. Either escape `?` as `\?` or use plaintext method `$line.replace('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: Hi, if I use `replace('foo', 'bar')` i get error: 
`Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'Replace'.`

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` instead of `Select-Object -Property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you have to build the regular expression,
[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/cI0zC7/2)

```
$link=Get-MSHotfix|Where-Object {$_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-20000))}|Select-Object -Property KBArticle 

foreach($line in $link){

        [String]$line = $line -replace "http:\/\/support\.microsoft\.com\/\?kbid=",'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/'


    [String]$line
}
```

or you use substring:

```
$link=Get-MSHotfix|Where-Object {$_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-20000))}|Select-Object -Property KBArticle 


foreach($line in $link){

        [String]$line = 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/' + $line.substring(35)


    [String]$line
}
```

cut the strings by first 35 characters and add it to your url.

EDIT:

very interesting, what also works is the other kind of replace...

```
$link=Get-MSHotfix|Where-Object {$_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-20000))}|Select-Object -Property KBArticle 

foreach($line in $link){

    [String]$line = $line.replace("http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=",'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/')


[String]$line
}
```

I'm a bit confused...

if you use -replace you have to take a regex if you call the function .replace() you need to give a string.

Comment: Hello, this works, only now I get it like this
`@{KBArticle=https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3160005}` How can I remove `@{KBArticle and }` from output?
Thanks

Comment: This works

`$link=Get-MSHotfix|Where-Object {$_.Installedon -gt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-20000))}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty KBArticle 

foreach($line in $link){

        $line = $line -replace "http:\/\/support\.microsoft\.com\/\?kbid=",'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/'


    $line
}`

Comment: with `$line.KBArticle`  --> the output is an object with the property KBArticle --> you have to access the property instead of `[String]$line` --> use `[String]$line.KBArticle`